# Права пользователей на папки

Tags: linux

Начал изучать LInux и тут такая задача:

Создайте директории и пользователей, а также выдайте им права так, чтобы выполнялись следующие пункты:

- Есть пользователь «бухгалтерия» (Buh), который имеет полный доступ к директории Buhgalter и полный доступ к директории отдела снабжения
- Есть пользователь отдела HR (Hr), который должен иметь полный доступ к директории HR и директории PR
- Есть пользователь отдела PR (Pr), который должен иметь полный доступ к директории PR и полный доступ к директории бухгалтерии
- Есть пользователь отдела снабжения (Sup), который должен иметь полный доступ к директории Supply_department и доступ на чтение для директории бухгалтерии
- Есть сотрудник техподдержки (HD_1), который должен иметь полный доступ для директорий PR, Supply_department, Buhgalter и доступ на чтение к HR.

В папках пользователей создайте пустые файлы и выдайте рекурсивные права.
Для других пользователей, в том числе для тех, которые будут созданы позднее, доступа в папки пользователей из условия задания быть не должно.
Все директории должны находится в /var/data.

вот моя последовательность команд:

```
    cd ~
    sudo mkdir /var/data
    cd /var/data
    sudo mkdir Buhgalter HR PR Supply_department
    sudo useradd Buh
    sudo useradd HR
    sudo useradd PR
    sudo useradd Sup
    sudo useradd HD_1
    sudo touch /var/data/hr/filehr
    sudo touch /var/data/pr/filepr
    sudo touch /var/data/Buhgalter/filebuh
    sudo touch /var/data/Supply_department/filesup
```

Но я не совсем понимаю, как дать пользователям права, как описано в ТЗ.

Есть идея создать группы Buh, PR, Supply, HR и добавлять туда пользователей. Но как дать ограниченные права конкретному пользователю

Comment: как я понимаю, в линукс права определяются по принадлежности папки пользователю. вам придется сначала сделать [chown](https://firstvds.ru/technology/linux-permissions), а потом добавить/убрать права пользователю/остальным c помощью chmod. сделать так что Вася может все с папкой, Петя читать из нее, а Коля ничего с ней делать не может не получится.

Comment: setfacl, обычные права не работают в много пользовательских системах

Comment: Нет, требуется без ACL. Есть идея для групп давать права полные, а там, где нужны права ограниченные, давать их владельцу файла.

Comment: В общем, как я и говорил, надо для ограничения прав конкретного пользователя надо было делать его владельцем файла и ограничить его права